# where is the information about the "main" function stored in c, where the main defined?

Tags: c

in c where is the main function defined, is it defined in compiler or in header files, how does the compiler know the meaning of "main" word? i haven't been able to get the answer anywhere, please please please help.

Comment: This would be hardcoded in the compiler core, yes. But what are you planning to do? Create a fork of the compiler that allows you to use other names for the program's main entry point?

Comment: @MrLister: Not really hardcoded... Also, there are very legitimate uses for that, for example if you're compiling a kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the operating system defines an entry point (on Unix, it's genrally the `start` function), which is automatically called by the operating system (in particular, the loader). Your C compiler is supplied with a minimal runtime setup (again, on Unix, it's most likely called `crt0.o`), which is a precompiled object file, that sets up the C library internals then calls your main() function. So the compiler has nothing to do with it; it's crt0.o and the operating system that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in neither. `main` is not actually a keyword in C - it's just a regular function.

The standard C library includes a function, which sets up the initial environment (collects `argc`, `argv` and so on) and calls your `main` function.

The linker then puts the location of that function in the object file as the entry point.

You can see `glibc`'s entry point here:
http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.15/dl-init_8c_source.html

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `main` function is part of the language specification.
The compiler has special code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

When a copiler generates an application there are two main parts to the code:

1. The OS glue code
2. The application that was written by the programmer (including main)

The generated application when run executes the OS glue code then calls the function main. Thus when the compiler is generating the code for the application if it can not find the function main will fail to compile. If it finds it then it knows its address and thus how to call it.

There is nothing else really special about main (apart from the compiler looks for it).

Answer (score 0):

`Call stack` stores the information of active subroutines of a computer program.Since, Main() function is already defined  by compiler.So,it should be stored in a datastructure similar to call stack.please look at this link 
     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

C allows two different types of execution environments: *Freestanding* and *Hosted*. Refer 
5.1.2/1:

> Two execution environments are defined: freestanding and hosted. In both cases,
>   program startup occurs when a designated C function is called by the execution
>   environment.

However:

> The manner and timing of such initialization are
>   otherwise unspecified. Program termination returns control to the execution
>   environment.

In a freestanding environment (think of embedded systems) as per 5.1.2.1/1:

> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any
>   benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program
>   startup are implementation-defined.

Most (desktop) common systems belong to the *hosted* category i.e. one where there is a host or OS which provides a context for the program to run. In such environments (see 5.1.2.2.1/1):

> The function called at program startup is named main.

`main` is not a keyword (i.e. not in the set defined by 6.4.1). Think of it as a binding contract for C programs to run and be run from a system which has a host (OS). Thus it is both the vendors' responsibility to allow bootstrapping code to look for this particular function and the programmers responsibility to provide a suitable definition.

Answer (score 0):

> in c where is the main function defined, is it defined in compiler or
>   in header files

(disclaimer: windows tinted description)

The function `main` is part of the C standard and is generally the starting point in the program and needs no special header. The name "main" hasn't really a significance for the operating system, instead the linker will setup main as the starting point of the program by default but the name could in fact be any other function in the program.

The linker has the option of specifying another entry point in the program, it is just the starting point where the program starts executing but whether it is called main, _tmain or WinMain doesn't matter - from the point of view of the operating system.